# jQuery jTable: horizontal scrolling, autofilter and subtotal

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-jtable

I am using [jQuery jTable](http://www.jtable.org/) plugin to CRUD a database.

I have the following doubts:

1. How do I create a horizontal scrolling since my table has too many fields?

**Image 1:** Horizontal scrolling gone wrong with jQuery jTable
[image]

2. How do I create an autofilter feature and how do I add subtotal and total columns (like Excel or LibreOffice Calc)?

**Image 2:** Excel spreaddsheet with autofilters and subtotals
[image]

**Image 3:** Excel spreadsheet with applied autofilters changing the subtotal value
[image]

***Details:***

- My table is paginated server-side
- I am using PHP and SQL Server 2012